# Laravel nested eager loading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have tables `users`, `roles`, their pivot table `role_user`, and table `comments` in my DB. I am trying to make a query where I could get all the users with their roles for comments. I am not sure how to do this, so far I have a query that looks like this:

```
$comments = Comment::with('user')->where('article_id', $articleId)->get();
```

With that query I get the user for each comment, but when I tried to add roles, like this:

```
$comments = Comment::with('user', 'roles')->where('article_id', $articleId)->get();
```

Or, like this:

```
$comments = Comment::with('user.roles')->where('article_id', $articleId)->get();
```

But that didn't work. 
I have setup the relationships in Comment model like this:

```
class Comment extends Model
{

  public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }

  public function roles()
  {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Role', 'App\User');
  }
}
```

**Update**

Since this is the backend api endpoint and I am sending that data to Angular frontend, I just checked the results in the postman and there I get the data for user roles with this query:

```
$comments = Comment::with('user.roles')->where('article_id', $articleId)->get();
```

Then, the result looks like this:

```
"user":{"id":1,
        "first_name":"admin",
        "last_name":"admin",
        "photo":"","email":"admin@coop.com",
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":"2016-06-14 16:19:35",
        "roles":[{"id":1,
                  "name":"Admin",
                  "slug":"admin",
                  "description":null,
                  "parent_id":null,
                  "created_at":null,
                  "updated_at":null,
                  "pivot":{"user_id":1,
                           "role_id":1,
                           "created_at":"2016-06-14 14:14:25",
                           "updated_at":"2016-06-14 14:14:25",
                           "granted":1}
}]}}
```

But I don't get any data for the roles when I do console.log in my controller in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

try this it's working for me

```
$comments = Comment::with(['user', 'roles'])->where('article_id', $articleId)->get();
```

you should pass an argument as array for eager loading.

Thanks